# Get the static variable values of a class

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, runtime

I have a spring application deployed in tomcat. The application has a class (ClassWithStaticFields)with some static fields. I need to get the values of these static fields either from heap dump or from another external class(by manually placing the new class in the path of ClassWithStaticFields)

The external class when it tries to access the static field a null value is shown. I think this is because the process which started and loaded the static fields and the new class process are different.

The heap dump doesn't have any information about the class itself.

SELECT s.@staticFields FROM "com.ClassWithStaticFields" s

gives Your Query did not yield any result.

I am expecting to get/view  the value of static field of a class which is deployed in tomcat. I do not want answer to suggest to put a logger/sysout/print statements.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to know the static fields value in a class, first you need to know the class name. If you know the class name it would be easy then. ClassName.StaticField will give you the result.

Comment: But the war file is already deployed. Code change or addition of new class cannot be done

Comment: Do you want to know the static data from the another service which is running?